# Store objects in RDBMS in android

Tags: android

What is the recommended way to persist objects between uses of an app in the Android OS? These objects are of custom classes, not standard java classes.

Comment: Note: the answer to this question is provided by @mgv in the comments to his original answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android provides several ways to persist application data. If you are looking for a relational approach you should look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) and start using SQLite.

If you are going to persist the state of an activity you have to do it in the `onPause()` callback. If you want to persist data fetched in a service the basic rule is persist early, persist often.

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with the SQLite DB etc... I am asking what is the recommended method of storing objects of custom classes. Would this be serialization and storage in SQLite, or perhaps there is some other method? I don't believe it is possible to use saved instance state for custom objects?

Comment: What do you mean by custom classes? Of course you will have to do the object relational mapping by hand and map properties to table columns. If you want to save your objects directly consider using db4o instead of the relational approach.

Comment: by custom classes I mean classes I have written myself, not those that that are part of a java package like java.util or something.

Comment: As I've told you before, you have to map each object property you want to persist to a table column. Here (http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html) is an official sample that shows how to define such database schema. From there is all manual work. If you want to simplify all this take a look a http://www.db4o.com/android/, an object-oriented database that allows you to directly save your complex objects without any additional mapping.